# Product URLs are not working in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

If a product have more than one category then the product URL not showing properly. For example, product A assigned to two categories C1 and C2. If we click to enter into the category c1 and click the Product A (OR) enter into the category C2 and click the product A, in both cases, it goes to the product details page with the same URL which is based on the Category C1 because the product's default category is C1. But i don't want the same URL, it should be like as follows: 'http://www.example.com/C1/A', 'http://www.example.com/C2/A'. Its a default functionality of Prestashop, is any way to override this functionality?

Comment: This is the default behaviour. You can override this, but you have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a bit of development, but it will make you duplicate content on google because there are two different links on the same page.

Regards,

Comment: If ok, please close question :)